# Are argumentative questions allowed?

Tags: discussion, questions

See: [Why don't people use white space inside parentheses](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6512/why-dont-people-use-white-space-inside-parentheses)

To me, questions related to coding style / standards are clearly within the remit of Programmers.SE, however the tone of the question I linked is argumentative.

See: [What is better: Java or C#](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6284/what-is-better-java-or-c)

The content of the question itself seems ok, the title is very argumentative though.  An alternative that was suggested was: "What are the relative merits of Java and C#"

Given that a lot of subjective questions are also argumentative, where does the line get drawn?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The nature of SE sites is such that the very format discourages thread-long flame wars with multiple responses by the same handful of people.

This helps keep questions which are phrased argumentatively from descending into tit-for-tat flaming. Neither of the threads linked above have been *answered* argumentatively.

It would be naïve to suggest that flamewars won't happen here, but I have faith in the community and believe that argumentative, programming-culture-related threads should be allowed, as people come to subjective sites looking for multiple viewpoints. As long as the community can continue to provide those multiple viewpoints in a rationale manner, we'll be just fine.

Comment: I came here to say essentially this. If people are being responsible, closing because moderator 'x' thinks it _might_ descend into a flamewar is inappropriate. If it does, close it ASAP. If it doesn't, I don't see the problem with it.

Answer (score 6):

Argumentative questions, in the sense that they are liable to piss a lot of people off, aren't appropriate; but neither of the questions you linked are particularly argumentative.

Examples of inappropriate *argumentative* questions would be:

- [Do programmers have higher tendency to be atheists than non programmers?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/5555/do-programmers-have-higher-tendency-to-be-atheists-than-non-programmers)
- [Is the computing community homophobic?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6295/is-computing-community-homophobic)

I'd also include the following as examples of questions that are ostensibly on-topic, but worded in such a way that make them unnecessarily argumentative:

- [The lifecycle of "cool"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/311/the-lifecycle-of-cool)
- [MVC just the SEO of PHP programming?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2806/is-mvc-just-the-seo-of-php-programming)

While it'd be nice if people removed their answer to the question they are asking from the question itself, merely doing so isn't really grounds for a close. Down-voting questions with bad premises is more appropriate.

Comment: I disagree with you on the inappropriateness of your first set of questions. I think they are perfectly acceptable.

Comment: People should _not_ be required to self-censor just because a minority believes that they're out of line. If the tone of the question and the majority of answers is polite, _and_ the question is on-topic (which those questions are), I don't see the problem. If you don't like an on-topic question, simply don't read it.